# WebSocket connection to failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Good day guys

I'm building a chat app using ratchet and save data to mysql database. On localhost everything is working well and connection is established.

Now I have loaded the app on live server and login using SSH (Putty), then navigated to `php bin/chat-server.php` then on the browser console I get this error :

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://donorgametes.com:8080/' failed: Error
>   in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

This is my url to the app

https://donorgametes.com/MyApp/

My code :

```
<script>
    var conn = new WebSocket('wss://donorgametes.com:8080');
    conn.onopen = function (e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");

    };

    conn.onmessage = function (e) {
        showMessage(e.data, 'Others');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var messageElement = document.querySelector('#message');
        var message = messageElement.value;

        var messageData = {
            'userId': '12',
            'content': message
        }
        var messageDataJson = JSON.stringify(messageData);

        conn.send(JSON.stringify(messageDataJson));
        showMessage(message, 'Me');
        messageElement.value = '';
    });

    function showMessage(msg, sender) {
        var messageItem = document.createElement('li');
        var className = 'list-group-item';

        if (messageItem.classList)
            messageItem.classList.add(className);
        else
            messageItem.className += ' ' + className;

        messageItem.innerHTML = '<strong>' + sender + ': </strong>' + msg;
        document.querySelector('#chat-area > ul').appendChild(messageItem);
    }
</script>
```

Chat server

```
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);

$server->run();
```

How can I run this on live server and get a connection? What steps must I follow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebSocket connection to 'ws://mydomain.com:8084/?peer\_id=123' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR\_CONNECTION\_TIMED\_OUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873181/websocket-connection-to-ws-mydomain-com8084-peer-id-123-failed-error-in-c)

Comment: Port 8080 is not open on donorgametes.com, so either your server is not running (is there any output after starting chat-server.php?) or there is a firewall in the way.

Comment: @leberknecht no there's no output at all... I'm not sure how to check if there's firewall

Comment: Any one who can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking your app page source i found that you are using `localhost` for connection on line number: 38

`var conn = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:8080');`

Which is wrong, you should use your own domain name.

Second thing is after checking port forwarding on you domain i have found that port `8080` is blocked right now. So you should better ask your hosting provider to open port in `IPTABLES` for incoming connections or if you have root access then try this [Article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/10/01/useful-iptables-port-forwarding-patterns/) it might help you to allow port forwading.

Comment: you can check the port status here: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Answer (score 0):

On your site you're using a different port (35814).
So there might be just some confusion to set the right parameters.

```
<script>
    var conn = new WebSocket('wss://donorgametes.com:35814');
    conn.onopen = function (e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");

    };

    conn.onmessage = function (e) {
        showMessage(e.data, 'Others');
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var messageElement = document.querySelector('#message');
        var message = messageElement.value;

        var messageData = {
            'userId': '12',
            'content': message
        }
        var messageDataJson = JSON.stringify(messageData);

        conn.send(JSON.stringify(messageDataJson));
        showMessage(message, 'Me');
        messageElement.value = '';
    });

    function showMessage(msg, sender) {
        var messageItem = document.createElement('li');
        var className = 'list-group-item';

        if (messageItem.classList)
            messageItem.classList.add(className);
        else
            messageItem.className += ' ' + className;

        messageItem.innerHTML = '<strong>' + sender + ': </strong>' + msg;
        document.querySelector('#chat-area > ul').appendChild(messageItem);
    }
</script>
```

The shown error is fitting to the port in the script:

> (index):38 WebSocket connection to 'wss://donorgametes.com:35814/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: The problem still the same, was trying to use different port

Comment: ok,I think some important data about your configuration  might be missing, but I searched here on SO for [Ratchet Websocket log](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Ratchet+Websocket+log), I'd have a look if the log-file is showing some useful hint perhaps. Furthermore I found this specific answer, perhaps it's useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17905105/1019850.
Currently it's only guesswork, so you had to add more details, which would be also nice to see a solution here perhaps.

Comment: On point about the port: webserver and app have to use the same port naturally. Above for the webserver you've configured 8080, but probably you checked that after my answer already.